# Why is my OpenGL code not rendering anything?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I have been following the [LearnOpenGL Hello Triangle tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle), and nothing is rendering except the clear color.

Any help finding what is wrong would be appreciated.

Using LWJGL 3.2.3 OpenGL and GLFW bindings on MacOS.

My code:

```
// ---- WINDOW SETUP ----------------------------------
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);

    long window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create window");

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GL.createCapabilities();

    int[] fbWidth = new int[1];
    int[] fbHeight = new int[1];
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, fbWidth, fbHeight);
    glViewport(0, 0, fbWidth[0], fbHeight[0]);
    log.info("Framebuffer size: {} x {}", fbWidth[0], fbHeight[0]);

    glfwShowWindow(window);
    log.info("Created window");

    // ---- BUFFER SETUP ----------------------------------

    float[] vertices = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
             0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    int vao = glGenBuffers();
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    int vbo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0L);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    log.info("Created buffers");

    // ---- SHADER SETUP ----------------------------------

    String vertexShaderSource =
            "#version 330 core\n" +
            "layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n" +
            "}";
    String fragmentShaderSource =
            "#version 330 core\n" +
            "out vec4 fragColor;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "    fragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n" +
            "}";

    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        log.error("Vertex shader compilation failed:");
        log.error(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
        return;
    }

    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GLFW_FALSE) {
        log.error("Fragment shader compilation failed:");
        log.error(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
        return;
    }

    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    if (glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        log.error("Shader program linking failed:");
        log.error(glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
        return;
    }

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    log.info("Loaded shaders");

    // ---- MAIN LOOP ------------------------------------

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // ---- CLEANUP --------------------------------------

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
```

Comment: Stride should be `3 * sizeof(float)`, not 0 in `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: @Rish - 0 is a valid value indicating tightly-packed data: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml

Comment: @Maximus Minimus Thanks, TIL.

Answer (score 1):

```
int vao = glGenBuffers();
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

This should be using glGenVertexArrays, not glGenBuffers.